# lineNumber: 54; columnNumber: 26; The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int:scatter-gather'

Tags: spring-integration

I know its duplicate question but other solutions are not working please help, thanks.

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 54; columnNumber: 26; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int:scatter-gather'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" 
    xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
    xmlns:int-jmx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
       "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx/spring-integration-jmx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="springIntegeration.test1" /> -->

    <int:channel id="inputChannel" />
    <int:channel id="outputChannel" />

    <int:gateway id="scatterGatherGateway" service-interface="scatterGather.Gateway" default-request-channel="inputChannel" default-reply-channel="outputChannel" default-reply-timeout="3000"/>

    <!--
    <int:service-activator id="gatewayTestSO" input-channel="inputChannel" method="handleMessage" output-channel="outputChannel">
        <beans:bean class="scatterGather.GatewayTestSO" />
    </int:service-activator>
    -->
    
    <task:executor id="scatterChannelExecutor" pool-size="9" queue-capacity="0" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="scatterChannel" apply-sequence="true" task-executor="scatterChannelExecutor" />

    <int:service-activator id="subTransactionVO1Enricher" input-channel="scatterChannel" method="enrich">
        <beans:bean class="scatterGather.SubTransactionVO1Enricher" />
    </int:service-activator>
    
    <beans:bean id="aggregator" class="scatterGather.Aggregator" />
    <beans:bean id="aggregatorMessageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore" />
    
    <int:scatter-gather 
        id="scatterGather" 
        auto-startup="true" 
        input-channel="inputChannel" 
        output-channel="outputChannel" 
        scatter-channel="scatterChannel" 
        gather-timeout="2000" 
        requires-reply="true" >
        <int:gatherer>
            <int:aggregator 
                message-store="aggregatorMessageStore" 
                send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
                expire-groups-upon-completion="true" 
                group-timeout="1000"
                ref="aggregator" 
                method="aggregate" />
        </int:gatherer>
    </int:scatter-gather>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: What version of Spring Integration are you using? Are you seeing this at runtime? Or just in the IDE?

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell for pointing out version, I was using 4.0.3 which do not have this element added, changed version to 4.3.23, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just an IDE issue. Consider to use that one which is Spring-aware: IntelliJ IDEA or STS. As far as I know regular Eclipse tries to resolve an XSD for those xml configs from the Internet or some other local store. The Spring-aware resolves them from classpath, from jars where those XSDs are located.